# When to use read() or sysread()

Tags: perl, file, io

When is `sysread` better than `read` for fetching data in perl? The [`perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) sections on [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) and [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) give advice that is not entirely clear on when to choose which.

In a response to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36208336/2019415) I used [`Stream::Reader`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Stream::Reader). As an experiment I replaced `read` with `sysread` in `Reader.pm` and gained 9-10% throughput.  This seems too simple and - other than what I can glean from `perlfunc` - I am not clear on what the trade offs might be.

Comment: [ikegami beat you to it.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36315124/176646)

Comment: Once I get a good answer from him I'll post a response here :-D

Comment: You should post your answer on his question and delete this one since these are duplicate questions.

Comment: I was just about to post: *It appears to me that Stream::Reader supports streams with `:encoding` layers. As such, it can't use `sysread`.*

Comment: OK so maybe  the reason it returned the same results was because the data in that case was somewhat unusually boring or  because  I was using `Mode => "UB" ` in the constructor ...